# SoapFault - ystem.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ErrorLogs\ErrorLog20141017.txt' is denied

Tags: android, ksoap2

I have got following error during transferring data to web using soap webservices.

```
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_DATA, envelope);
```

> DBServiceNew.LoadXmlString(String projectName, String formName, String
>   userId, String xmlData)

Every thing good all the parameters, while GETTING error on **httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_DATA, envelope);**, I got this error on log cat.

```
10-17 10:21:42.724: W/System.err(6575): SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ErrorLogs\ErrorLog20141017.txt' is denied.
10-17 10:21:42.724: W/System.err(6575):    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
10-17 10:21:42.724: W/System.err(6575):    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
10-17 10:21:42.724: W/System.err(6575):    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
10-17 10:21:42.724: W/System.err(6575):    at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
10-17 10:21:42.724: W/System.err(6575):    at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
10-17 10:21:42.724: W/System.err(6575):    at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append)
10-17 10:21:42.724: W/System.err(6575):    at CreateLogFiles.ErrorLog(String sPathName, String sErrMsg)
10-17 10:21:42.724: W/System.err(6575):    at DBServiceNew.LoadXmlString(String projectName, String formName, String userId, String xmlData)
10-17 10:21:42.724: W/System.err(6575):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@42d34eb8
10-17 10:21:42.724: W/System.err(6575):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:136)
10-17 10:21:42.724: W/System.err(6575):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:137)
10-17 10:21:42.724: W/System.err(6575):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:96)
10-17 10:21:42.734: W/System.err(6575):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:189)
10-17 10:21:42.734: W/System.err(6575):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95
```

anyone know about this type of error, please provide me some hints how to solve such type of problelm. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is an issue with your server, have you been able to hit the server directly using something like SOAP UI. 
I dont think your android code is at fault here.